# Python: Find distance between characters of elements of array

Tags: python, list

If I have a list

```
L = [
'AXX', 
'XXX', 
'XXG'
]
```

Suppose it is known that the 'distance' between an `A` and an adjacent `X` is 1 and the 'distance' between an `A` and a diagonally located `X` is 2. How would I be able to translate that into python?

Thanks

Comment: describe your question properly, like what is `G` do you need to only construct distance of all `X`??? from starting `A` only.. clarify your statement, add some expected output and your attempt to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your definition the distance between two cells in a matrix is quite simply their row difference plus their column difference , so all you need is a function that takes the position of the reference cell and the position of the other cell and does the said calculation:

```
def distance(row1, column1, row2, column2):
    return abs(row2 - row1) + abs(column2 - column1)
```

so that:

```
distance(0, 0, 1, 1) # distance between A and the diagonally located X
```

would be `2`.